# Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

When i execute ***My request:***

```
UPDATE vm s , (SELECT MAX(id) FROM vm) as p 
SET s.title = 'TEST' 
WHERE s.id = p.id;
```

I have this error ***Error:***

```
Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'
```

I don't understand

Comment: What are you trying to do? The sub-query returns no column id.

Comment: If I understand your query correctly, shouldn't it be `WHERE s.id = p`?

Comment: You created a column called `p` and then tried to reference it as `p.id` when there is no `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you need to give a name to the max(id)

```
UPDATE vm s , (SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM vm) as p 
SET s.title = 'TEST' 
WHERE s.id = p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit `join`:

```
UPDATE vm s JOIN
       (SELECT MAX(id) as pid FROM vm) p 
       ON s.id = p.pid
    SET s.title = 'TEST' ;
```

Or, more simply, use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
UPDATE vm
    SET title = 'TEST'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `JOIN` definitely the way to go, if MySQL is anything like MSSQL then aliases aren't supported in a `WHERE` clause.